# Al iniciar sesión con Facebook , Me cierra la app al enviar los datos a otra actividad

Tags: android-studio, login, kotlin, facebook

estoy iniciando sesión con la librería de facebook y al precionar  el botón btningresar, inicia sesión pero se cierra la app y no me carga la la segunda actividad que es DatosActivity en donde envío el nombre y la foto , no me carga el nombre ni la foto de perfil del usuario , que error estoy cometiendo en el código;  ¿Cual y donde esta el error?

esta es el MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var callbackManager:CallbackManager?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        var loginbutton=findViewById<LoginButton>(R.id.loginbutton)
        loginbutton.setReadPermissions(("email"))

        loginbutton.registerCallback(callbackManager,object :FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                iraDatos()
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"se calcelo el inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
            }
        })
    }

    private fun iraDatos() {
        val intent=Intent(this,DatosActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)
    }
}
```

esta es la segunda actividad, a donde se envian los datos

```
class DatosActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos)

        var tvusuario=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvUsuario)
        var imgusuario=findViewById<ProfilePictureView>(R.id.imgProfile)
        var btnsalir=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnsalirFacebook)

        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()==null){
            iraMain()
            }else{
            var  profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile()
            tvusuario.setText(profile.name)
            imgusuario.setProfileId(profile.id)
        }

        btnsalir.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()

            iraMain()
        })
    }

    private fun iraMain() {
        val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Si la ejecutas en modo debug, te marca el error?

Comment: me sale , que el id no existe y no se puede cargar debido a la falta de permisos o no admite esta operación.